# Animating color in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Loving fabric and trying to get to grips with it all.

First, I created a text like this:

```
newtext = new fabric.Text('EUI', {
    fontFamily: 'UbuntuL',
    fontSize: 70,
    fill: '#555',
    selectable: false,
});
canvas.add(newtext);
```

But, It can't change color with animate:

```
newtext.animate({
    fill:'#f00',
}, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: fabric.util.ease.easeOutCubic,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
});
```

Can someone explain please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In [this Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/0mcxSePoI4c), a user explains that:

> color animation is not yet implemented in fabric.js

So the only thing you can do is to implement something to animate color by yourself.